# Reshape Data Frame to Add Rows for Unique Year and Add New Sequence

Tags: r, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like the below:

```
id=c(10,10,10,25,25,25,300,4000)
yrs=c(2010,2012,2013,2008,2010,2011,2008,2008)
yrf=c(2011,2013,2013,2009,2014,2012,2014,2013)
occ=c(5656,621,7,8,10,8,15,19)
df=data.frame(id,yrs,yrf,occ)
```

I would like to reshape it so that each identity, occupation and year in the range from yrs to yrf has it's own row corresponding to a new row "year". I would also like to have a new column  "sequence" that is simply "occ" except where rows with the same year and id have multiple "occ"'s, in which case it would be a string of the different "occ"'s separated by a space. The finished product would look like this:

```
id  yrs      yrf    year    occ sequence
10  2010    2011    2010    5656    5656
10  2010    2011    2011    5656    5656
10  2012    2013    2012    621 621
10  2012    2013    2013    621 621 7
10  2013    2013    2013    7   621 7
25  2008    2009    2008    8   8
25  2008    2009    2009    8   8
25  2010    2014    2010    10  10
25  2010    2014    2011    10  10 8
25  2010    2014    2012    10  10 8
25  2010    2014    2013    10  10
25  2010    2014    2014    10  10
25  2011    2012    2011    8   10 8
25  2011    2012    2012    8   10 8
300 2008    2014    2008    15  15
300 2008    2014    2009    15  15
300 2008    2014    2010    15  15
300 2008    2014    2011    15  15
300 2008    2014    2012    15  15
300 2008    2014    2013    15  15
300 2008    2014    2014    15  15
40002008    2013    2008    19  19
40002008    2013    2009    19  19
40002008    2013    2010    19  19
40002008    2013    2011    19  19
40002008    2013    2012    19  19
40002008    2013    2013    19  19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach (with comments, so you can see what's going on at each step):

```
## Figure out how much longer we need to make the data
Expand <- (df[, "yrf"] - df[, "yrs"])+1

## "expand" the original data.frame with the vector just created
df2 <- df[rep(rownames(df), Expand), ]

## Generate the sequence of years, 
##    again using the "Expand" vector just created
df2$year <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(Expand), function(x) 
  df$yrs[x] + (sequence(Expand[x])-1)), use.names = FALSE)

## Use ave, grouping by id and year, 
##    to paste together the values from the occ column
df2$sequence <- with(df2, ave(occ, id, year, FUN = function(x) 
  paste(unique(x), collapse = " ")))
```

Here's what the first 10 rows of the output look like:

```
head(df2, 10)
#     id  yrs  yrf  occ year sequence
# 1   10 2010 2011 5656 2010     5656
# 1.1 10 2010 2011 5656 2011     5656
# 2   10 2012 2013  621 2012      621
# 2.1 10 2012 2013  621 2013    621 7
# 3   10 2013 2013    7 2013    621 7
# 4   25 2008 2009    8 2008        8
# 4.1 25 2008 2009    8 2009        8
# 5   25 2010 2014   10 2010       10
# 5.1 25 2010 2014   10 2011     10 8
# 5.2 25 2010 2014   10 2012     10 8
```

Comment: I have a quick followup question. In the formula above, two "occ"'s with separate start dates but the same code are collapsed together. If I wanted to differentiate these two, what would I do? In this scenario it would be possible for the same person to have a repeat of the same "occ" in their "sequence" for a year, if one started at 2010 and went to 2011 and the other started at 2011 and went to 2012. I tried to simply add 'yrs' to to ave from the second to last line of code, thinking this would solve it, but it crashed my computer.

Comment: @user2980723, I don't quite understand your follow-up question. Perhaps you can do something with the "rownames" of the resulting `data.frame` to help distinguish what it is you're trying to look for.

Answer (score 0):

```
NewRows <- function(x) {
  n <- x[3] - x[2] + 1
  data.frame(rep(x[1], n), rep(x[2], n), rep(x[3], n), x[2]:x[3], rep(x[4], n))
}

GetSequence <- function(x) 
  paste(df2$occ[df2[, 1] == x[1] & df2[, 4] == x[4]], collapse = " ")

df2 <- do.call("rbind", apply(df, 1, NewRows))
colnames(df2) <- c("id", "yrs", "yrf", "year", "occ")

df2$sequence <- apply(df2, 1, GetSequence)
```